# prepared statement failing for "SELECT" command, using mysqli in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been able to execute multiple prepared statements using mysqli (in PHP).
However, for some reason the prepared statements always encounter an error when I try running a "SELECT" command.
For example, the following line will succeed:

```
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("UPDATE events SET category='m' WHERE id=(?)");
```

However, the following line will fail:

```
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE id=(?)");
```

When I say fail, I mean that the next three lines will return 1 for the UPDATE command (indicating that one row was changed)...

```
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->affected_rows;
```

The next three lines will return 0 for SELECT:

```
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->num_rows;
```

For the record, I'm aware that prepared statements aren't that efficient for a single SELECT - this question is mostly academic.

Comment: substituting $stmt->affected_rows with $stmt->num_rows for the SELECT command gives a 0. So this still doesn't solve the problem - I'm expecting a 1.

Comment: `I'm aware that prepared statements aren't that efficient for a single SELECT` - who's been suggesting that? They're no more nor less efficient than any SQL query

Comment: That seemed to be a recurring opinion in a number of blogs. The claim was that since you have to communicate with the MySQL server twice (once with the prepared statement, then a second time with the actual parameters), the double-trip has a performance cost. Do you think this is incorrect?

Comment: It is the execute function that sends both Statement and the Bind Vars to MySQL, not two separate steps. MySQL will recognise that it is a prepared statement and check its compiled statement cache. If the statement is already in cache, it will load it and use it; if not, then it will compile the statement and store it in the compiled statement cache. Then it will add the bind vars to its execution..... there is still only one communication with the database server for both statement and bind vars, not a separate communication for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function (affected_rows) only works with queries which update a table. In order to get the number of rows from a SELECT query, use mysqli_stmt_num_rows() instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php

**Make sure you store the result first!!**

```
$stmt->execute();

/* store result */
$stmt->store_result();

printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);
```

Comment: i think the best way is to bind the result and fetch as per the example here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Answer (score 1):

What do you get if you do this?

```
echo $stmt->num_rows;
```

You cannot use affected rows method for SELECT statement!

Comment: Thanks - I get a 0. Which shouldn't happen - I'm expecting a 1.

Comment: see my answer above, you need to store the result to get a non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.